# Value of Hiddenfield not found in javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have spent the couple days researching my issue and have not been able to get it to work correctly.  I know there are a few topics here that are related to this issue and reading them has helped me but I'm at a bit of a roadblock and would appreciate a push in the right direction.

I wrote a small .NET 3.5 VB.NET web application that allows users to maintain some data.  It consists of 3 pages.  One requirement I was not completely fond of was that the user wanted to make all of her changes then hit a save button at the end instead of saving back to the DB each time she applied her changes to the grid.

I'm using an session object to store a collection of objects on each page and want to prompt the user with a dialog if they attempt to change the value of a dropdown or leave the page when there are pending actions.  After a lot of research here and in other places, I decided to create a hidden field on the page and update its value each time the action collection is updated on the server side.  Then I want to evaluate that value and if it's greater than 0, I want to prompt the user to save changes.

My function:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock2" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
        function confirmExit()
        {
            var actionCount = $get('<%=ActionCounterField.ClientID %>').value;
            if (actionCount > 0) {
                alert("Pending Changes!");
                  }
            }

        </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

My hidden field declaration:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="ActionCounterField" runat="server" />
```

My server side code:

```
Protected Sub UpdateActionCount()

    ActionCounterField.Value = GoalCategoryActionList.Count

End Sub
```

When I debug the application and add a record to my grid, the server side code is executed correctly.  I have also verified that the hidden control is found by the javascript function.  What I haven't been able to figure out, though, is why the hidden field value is not found by the function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: View the rendered HTML.  Is the HiddenField still given an ID of ActionCounterField, or has something been prepended to it?  Investigate the ClientIDMode property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Comment: Thank you, Garrison.  In the rendered HTML, the function appears to find the correct control but not the value:  var actionCount = $get('ctl00_MainContent_ActionCounterField').value;  Here's the HTML from the actual control rendering:  <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContent$ActionCounterField" id="ctl00_MainContent_ActionCounterField" />

Comment: If you put the value hard-coded in there, does the JavaScript find the value then?

Comment: Yes it does.  I used 'Value="5"' and that value was found.  I think it may either have something to do with the Telerik Ajax Manager or maybe the value is getting reset before the window.onbeforeunload is fired.  I haven't been able to verify either, though.  I've used the error console in the F12 tools for IE9 and nothing shows up.

Comment: I think you're on the right track with regards to the order of operations.  Wish I could help you more--only thing I'd try is putting the value in something like a Label (which you could set to display:none in CSS).  I'm wondering if Telerik doesn't like something about the ASP HiddenField.  I'd also try using a non-ASP input type=hidden with a runat=server on it so you can access in code-behind.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you again.  I'll try your suggestions after softball...  :)

Comment: Have you tried jQuery?  Also, any particular reason you are doing this on the server side?

Comment: Doug, I have not yet tried jQuery.  My only reason for attempting to do it server side is that I have the session object for each page that stores a collection of changed objects.  I need a way to prompt the user if there are pending changes and save those changes if the user wishes.  If no changes are pending I want them to be able to move about the application freely.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out how to do this.  I won't claim it's the most elegant solution but it works exactly how I want it to work so I'm happy.  Thank you for the responses.  I appreciate the help.

First, I changed the hidden field to a telerik RadTextBox and set it up to not display.  The RadTextBox just appears to play better with the RadGrid than the hiddenfield was.

```
<telerik:RadTextBox id="ActionCounterField" runat="server" style="display: none;" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Then I wired it up in the AjaxManager to be changed by my RadGrid.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ActionCounterField"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

I conditionally call the confirmation function.  When my user hits the save or undo button, the changes are persisted to the DB or undone without confirmation.  If they attempt to leave the page in any other way, however, they are prompted to save their changes.  If they hit "OK" the save button handler is called on the server side.  If they hit "Cancel", the undo button handler is called.

```
var allowConfirm = true
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
    var actionCountHolder = document.getElementById("<%=ActionCounterField.ClientID %>");
    var actionCount = actionCountHolder.value;
    if (allowConfirm == true) 
    {
        if (actionCount > 0) 
        {
            var conf = confirm("You have pending changes.  Save them?");
            if (conf == true) 
            {
                var saveButton = document.getElementById("<%=btnSave.ClientID %>");
                saveButton.click()
            }
            else 
            {
                var cancelButton = document.getElementById("<%=btnCancel.ClientID %>");
                cancelButton.click();
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        allowConfirm = true;
    }
}
```

Also, I have the save and undo buttons calling the disableConfirm function on their OnClientClick action.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="disableConfirm()" runat="server" Text="Apply"  />
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" OnClick="btnUndo_Click" OnClientClick="disableConfirm()" runat="server" Text="Undo"  />
```